# Table with two tier headers or Multi Level Headers in selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

how to handle in selenium web driver if a web table having multi level header and their child header also same? [SampleImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgIjN.jpg)

```html
<table>
  <col>
  <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
  <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Mars</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Venus</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Produced</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
    <th scope="col">Produced</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Teddy Bears</th>
    <td>50,000</td>
    <td>30,000</td>
    <td>100,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Board Games</th>
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, exactly? Are you trying to select one of the cells in the table?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Below code you can get all the details:

```
String P=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/th[1]")).getText();
```

String S=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2]/th[2]")).getText();

String T =driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[3]/th")).getText();
String B =driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/th")).getText();

System.out.println("\n"+"******MARS Details*******"+"\n");

for(int i=3; i<=4;i++) {
    for(int j=1; j<=2;j++) {
    WebElement x = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]"));

```
if(i==3 && j==1)
    System.out.println(T+" "+P+" "+x.getText()+"\n");
else if(i==3 && j==2)
    System.out.println(T+" "+S+" "+x.getText()+"\n");
else if(i==4 && j==1)
    System.out.println(B+" "+P+" "+x.getText()+"\n");
else if(i==4 && j==2)
    System.out.println(B+" "+S+" "+x.getText()+"\n"+"\n");

}
```

}

System.out.println("******VENUS Details*******"+"\n");

for(int i=3; i<=4;i++) {
    for(int j=3; j<=4;j++) {
    WebElement x = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]"));

```
if(i==3 && j==3)
    System.out.println(T+" "+P+" "+x.getText()+"\n");
else if(i==3 && j==4)
    System.out.println(T+" "+S+" "+x.getText()+"\n");
else if(i==4 && j==3)
    System.out.println(B+" "+P+" "+x.getText()+"\n");
else if(i==4 && j==4)
    System.out.println(B+" "+S+" "+x.getText()+"\n");

}
```

}